# SharePoint 2013 Parallel Approval Workflow with Cancel on First Rejection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow-manager, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to build an approval workflow in SharePoint 2013 that will assign in parallel, tasks to multiple approvers. For a request to get approved, a request needs to get 2 approvals, however, if one approver rejects, the whole workflow completes with the status of rejected.

In SharePoint 2010, there used to be an option to enable Cancel on First Rejection, but in SharePoint 2013 (using CompositeTask activity), Microsoft has removed this option. So far, a lot of the examples I have seen have claimed their examples will work in SharePoint 2013 only to find out, their examples have never been tested in SharePoint 2013.

Has anyone been successful in implementing this type of workflow in SharePoint 2013?